# How do you ensure that a third-degree Bezier curve is a straight line segment?

Tags: solution-verification, bezier-curve

Suppose that we have a Bezier curve of degree $3$. How can I ensure that the curve will be a straight line?

So as an example take this figure

[image: Example 3th degree Bizier curve]

I think that we can guarantee that the red line is a straight line if the weights of $b_1$ and $b_2$ are always zero with given parameter $t \in \space [0,1]$.

Comment: What do you mean by “weights”?

Comment: $\vec{x}(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\vec{b}_iB^n_i(t)$ with $B^n_i(t) = \binom{n}{i}(1-t)^{n-i}t^i$ where $\vec{b}_i$ are control points and $B^n_i(t)$ are ‘weights’.

Comment: The $B^n_i(t)$ is called basis functions. When talking about "weights" of control points in the context of Bezier curves or B-spline curves (or even NURBS), it is referring to the last dimension value in the homogeneous coordinates for the control points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cubic Bezier curve will be a straight line when all the 4 control points are collinear.

Comment: If the middle points have always weight zero, wouldn’t it be collinear?

Comment: It will be. But that will make the curve a rational Bezier curve.